# iTextSharp: Rectangle is not showing in Acrobat Reader

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp v5.1.
I create a PDF file with multiple pages. WHen I open this pdf in Chrome it looks as expected, but when I open this in the SystemViewer of Win8 parts of the context is missing. And in Acrobat Reader parts are missing as well.

I managed to track down the problem: When I draw a line, rectangle or roundedRectangle all following text is not showing anymore until I create a new page.

I'm just writing text, no images and I have no form objects.
When I analyze my pdf using http://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx
I get

```
Page  ObjNo  Description
0      0  The form xobject Xf2 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
9      0  The file is corrupt and cannot be repaired. Some of the contents can possibly be recovered.
```

Searching all day I understand Xf2 has something to do with forms, which I don't use.

Here's the code to create the document:

```
        var document = new Document();
        document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

        // Set template for the title page
        TitlePageEventHandler("template.pdf"));
        writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
        writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;

        // Open document
        document.Open();

        // Add MetaTags
        document.AddTitle("My title");
        document.AddSubject("My subject");
        document.AddAuthor("Me");
        document.AddCreator("iTextSharp v5.1");
        document.AddCreationDate();
        document.AddProducer();
```

This is the code to write text:

```
        protected static float ShowText(
        PdfContentByte cb, 
        Font font, 
        float x, 
        float y, 
        float width, 
        float height, 
        string text, 
        bool simulate = false, 
        int alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT)
    {
        var phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(text, font));
        var column = new ColumnText(cb);
        column.SetSimpleColumn(x, y, x + width, y - height, LineHeight, Element.ALIGN_LEFT | Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        column.SetText(phrase);
        column.Alignment = alignment;
        column.Go(simulate);
        return column.LinesWritten * LineHeight;
    }
```

And this is the code of drawing the rectangle:

```
        protected static void DrawRectangle(
        PdfContentByte cb, 
        BaseColor strokeColor, 
        BaseColor fillColor, 
        float left, 
        float top, 
        float right, 
        float bottom)
    {
        cb.SetColorStroke(strokeColor);
        cb.SetColorFill(fillColor);
        cb.SetLineDash(0, 0); // no dashed line
        cb.MoveTo(left, top);
        cb.LineTo(right, top);
        cb.LineTo(right, bottom);
        cb.LineTo(left, bottom);
        cb.ClosePathFillStroke();
    }
```

This is to draw a line:

```
        protected static void DrawLine(
        PdfContentByte cb,
        BaseColor strokeColor,
        float left,
        float top,
        float right,
        float phase = 0)
    {
        cb.SetColorStroke(strokeColor);
        if (phase >= 0)
        {
            cb.SetLineDash(phase, phase); <== This line is causing the problem
        }

        cb.MoveTo(left, top);
        cb.LineTo(right, top);
        cb.Stroke();
    }
```

When I call ShowText and next DrawRectangle and ShowText the PDF is showing OK in Chrome, but in other viewers only the first text is shown and nothing after it.
Without DrawRectangle the pdf, including headers and footers is rendered OK in all viewers.

Please advice how to solve this.

Comment: Please also share the PDF file for analysis. That been said, though, *iTextSharp v5.1* is very old. Try updating.

Comment: I created a new project which is creating only parts of the PDF and found the problem. When I remove cb.SetLineDash() the rectangles and lines appear again. As suggested I will also try to update to a new version

Comment: I updated to v5.5.6 using NuGet and I still have the problem. For now I solved it by removing the call to SetLineDash(), I used it only to draw a dashed line under my header. I can live with a default line ;)

Comment: *I updated to v5.5.6 using NuGet and I still have the problem. For now I solved it by removing the call to SetLineDash()* - ok, so that is something to look into...